# bash is changing my tr statement

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

Running a bash (4.1.2) script with the trace options -v and -x the following code

```
for Option in "$@"; do
OptName=$(echo $Option | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
```

results in

```
+ for Option in '"$@"'
echo $Option | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
++ echo -debug
++ tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
+ OptName=-DEBUG
```

which is what I expect.  However, another user running from the same host with the same bash version results in

```
+ for Option in '"$@"'
echo $Option | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
++ echo -debug
++ tr r r
+ OptName=-debug
```

Notice the translate command has been changed to "tr r r".  So far it's just this one user so it has to be something in the environment (right?).

Any suggestions on what could be causing this ?

Comment: You have a file name `r` in the current directory.  Try this: `echo [:lower:]`.  Then try this: `touch r; echo [:lower:]; echo '[:lower:]'`.

Comment: In passing, you should probably also quote `$Option` too, and if you can depend on a new enough Bash (>=4), you can avoid the sub-shell: `OptName="${Option,,}"`.  If not, you can still simplify a bit: `OptName=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$Option")`.

Answer (score 8):

you have a file named `r` so `[:upper:]` is expanded into `r`.

try

```
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

(edit) my test

```
%_ ls
%_ echo [:upper:]
[:upper:]
%_ touch r
%_ echo [:upper:]
r
%_
```

bash parses your command line in several phases, one of which is "globbing" aka filename expansion. So when bash sees `tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`, it goes and finds the tr binary, then sees the the `[ ... ]` brackets and says "ah, so you'd like to match files that are named with one of the following characters: `:`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `e`, or `r`. I see a file named `r` -- here you go!

If there was no r file, bash cannot and does not expand the `[...]` globbing.

Comment: I created a file named 'r' and ran the same bash script; the problem did not occur.  Can you please explain why you think having a file named 'r' would cause bash to expand [:lower:] to 'r'.  Thanks..

Comment: I modified the answer to include an explanation of the problem and another example to clarify this. (It might take a bit until the update shows up).

Comment: ok.. you're certainly correct about this.  I still don't understand though why bash is using variable substitution on [:upper:] to change it to 'r'.  Can you please explain... Thanks...

Comment: @kennethkahn see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion -- when you leave `[:upper:]` unquoted, bash sees the `[` and goes from there

Comment: I apologize for being dense about this but I just don't understand the comment "and goes from there".  Are you hinting that this is form of regex class substitution?  If so I don't understand why having a file named r would trigger this.

Comment: @kennethkahn, bash parses your command line in several phases, one of which is "globbing" aka filename expansion. So when bash sees `tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`, it goes and finds the `tr` binary, then sees the the `[` ... `]` brackets and says "ah, so you'd like to match files that are named with one of the following characters: `:`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `e`, or `r`. I see a file named `r` -- here you go! If there was no `r` file, bash cannot & does not expand the `[...]` glob.